# Which user applies to the execution context when executing messaging.sendEmail?

Tags: email-template, fls, executioncontext

I have a field that is used in an email template for which no FLS is granted in any profiles.

The Apex code that sends the email using **messaging.sendEmail()** is invoked from a trigger so I assume it to be running in **system mode** and that FLS is not relevant.

However, when that email is sent, and the trigger is executed by a record update, made when logged into a community as a user with profile **BoringUser**, the referenced field is not rendered into the email.

If I add read permissions for the **System Administrator** profile and perform the same operations. Log into community as **BoringUser**, cause a record update. Trigger fires and sends email, then the email received contains the expected merge field.

Why does granting read permission to the System Administrator profile influence field level access for code that should be running in **System Mode**?

Comment: one has to be a bit careful sometimes when logging into a community when already logged in as an employee. Can you verify the above when logging into the community in an incognito window as a `BoringUser`

Comment: @cropredy Thanks for the idea, unfortunately I have been testing this with a real login from an incognito window. No 'login as' involved.

Comment: Is there a controller extension involved that makes the update to the record from the community that enters the trigger?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I have very similar one and not sure who is the context of EmailTemplate generation... Even if sent from admin using anonymous apex it still seems to not have access to some records. Class already marked as `without sharing`

Comment: Unfortunately I never reached a definitive understanding of what was going on. I suspect that the developers that built Salesforce know but it doesn't seem to be documented. Note that my observations were around FLS, not record sharing but it seems like its probably the same situation

Answer (score 0):

In order to make trigger run in System Mode you have to mark the class as `without sharing` (`public without sharing class MyClass`). This would give **BoringUser** access to the fields he shouldn't have only to send the email.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Attilio Capocchiani as it happens the code concerned is  annotated with withoutSharing already.

I don't think that this is a factor though, sharing shouldn't affect FLS, only record visibility.